# find_dynamic_major function

Tags: linux-kernel

Kernel version v4.14 rc1 introduced the function `find_dynamic_major`. The version of this function in v4.19 rc5 is:

```
static int find_dynamic_major(void)
{
int i;
struct char_device_struct *cd;

for (i = ARRAY_SIZE(chrdevs)-1; i >= CHRDEV_MAJOR_DYN_END; i--) {
    if (chrdevs[i] == NULL)
        return i;
}

for (i = CHRDEV_MAJOR_DYN_EXT_START;
     i > CHRDEV_MAJOR_DYN_EXT_END; i--) {
    for (cd = chrdevs[major_to_index(i)]; cd; cd = cd->next)
        if (cd->major == i)
            break;

    if (cd == NULL || cd->major != i)
        return i;
}

return -EBUSY;
}
```

with the following values:

- `ARRAY_SIZE(chrdevs) = 255`
- `CHRDEV_MAJOR_DYN_END = 234`
- `CHRDEV_MAJOR_DYN_EXT_START = 511`
- `CHRDEV_MAJOR_DYN_EXT_END = 384`

In the first part, the function iterates through all major numbers between 254 and 234. The verified array positions are from 254 to 234. In the second part, the function iterates through all major numbers between 511 and 384. The function `major_to_index(i)` just returns i % 255, so the second function verifies array positions from 511 % 255, i.e. 1, to 384 % 255, i.e. 129. My question is, why are the positions between 130 and 233 not verified? Before this function was introduced, in order to find a free major number, all major numbers between 0 and 255 were verified. Why this was changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information in [the list of assigned devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html) and [the commit itself](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=a5d31a3f81c6fb13b381951bf6163444c0257e8b) provide more context.

Before this change, allocating a dynamic char device major did indeed loop down to 0, as you mention. However, a result under 234 wasn’t valid; it only resulted in a warning at allocation time, however in reality it was a duplicate char major, and if both devices (the statically-allocated device, and the dynamically-allocated device) ended up being used, seemingly unrelated failures would occur.

With this change, the valid ranges for dynamically-allocated char majors are enforced, and extended to allow for more than 20 such devices.

Comment: Thank you!! Now it makes sense